# Sencha touch 2 Store Dynamic Proxy Url

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I'm creating an application that has a high dependency on geographic location. I have variables 'GeoApp.app.geoLat' and GeoApp.app.geoLong' in app.js that are set with the geo coordinates.

If I console.out within any view, I have no problem accessing and outputing the values. Within a store, the values are empty as if it doesn't have access or perhaps variables haven't been defined or exist.

What is the best practice achieve what I am trying to do?

```
Ext.define('GeoApp.store.Places', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        model:'GeoApp.model.Place',
        autoLoad:'true',
        proxy: {
            type:'ajax',
            url:'googleapiurl/json?location=' + GeoApp.app.geoLat + ','+ GeoApp.app.geoLong + '&radius=500...',
            reader: {
                type:'json',
                rootProperty:'results'
            }
        }*/
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is set the proxy url before you load the store. Therefor you have to set `autoLoad` to `false`. You could use the code below in, for example, the `show()` function of your view component.

```
show: function(component, options){
    var store = Ext.getStore('Places');

    store.setProxy({
       url:'googleapiurl/json?location=' + GeoApp.app.geoLat + ','+ GeoApp.app.geoLong + '&radius=500...',
    });

    store.load();
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: This actually changes the whole proxy and not only the url. Would be better to do store.getProxy().setUrl(URL)

Answer (score 1):

That's because your store is created when you app launches and so is your url string. Therefore, `GeoApp.app.geoLat` and `GeoApp.app.geoLong` being null or undefined when you launch your app, they don't appear in your url.

What I would do is set the url to `googleapiurl/json?radiu=500...` and then add the `location` parameter as an `extraParam` of the proxy like so:

```
Ext.getStore('Places').getProxy().setExtraParams({
  location: GeoApp.app.geoLat + ',' + GeoApp.app.geoLong
});
```

Hope this helped

Comment: How would you then access the extra param location within the proxy url?

Comment: I don't understand. Where would you want to access the extra param ? Once you've set it there's nothing left to do on the client.